# Is there a component toggle between gyroscope and finger slide mode?

Tags: gyroscope, aframe

Is there a component can toggle the gyroscope? I want to make a button to enable or disable the usage of the gyroscope. I've read the official documentation but find nothing about this.

I do not want to close it in WebVR mode. I want to set a button toggle gyroscope. When I close mobile sensor, I can use finger slide screen to change the perspective.

Comment: Why would you do this? WebVR needs a gyro to watch the scene in you HMD.

Comment: I do not want to close it in WebVr mode.I want to set a button toggle gyroscope.when I close mobile sensor,I can use finger slide screen to change the perspective.Refer to this scene[istaging](http://vrviewer.istaging.com/#!/684173)

Comment: Now I understand. It wasn't clear in your question. Good question.

Comment: Perhaps detach/attach look-controls as you need, or copy-and-paste look-controls component to customize it.

Comment: Yeah,thanks for your advice,I customize the look-controls component in aframe-master.js . But I find If I use aframe-master.js rather than aframe.min.js will cause some components shared by others abnormal.Why?

Comment: The reason may be  aframe-master is unstable

Answer (score 0):

There was a pull request to A-Frame core to enable this feature, and I believe they determined to not add it. Instead it is best practice to enable this feature using a custom component.

Here is the pull request including commentary:
https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/2585

Here is the code that accomplishes what you are looking for, you can use it to make a custom component in your project:
https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/2585/files